# How to Deploy IE extension

Tags: .net, internet-explorer

i had developed one IE extension it is completely ok, i had used AddinExpress.IE.dll,Now i need to create exe for that so any one guide me how to create set up file

Answer (score 0):

For IE extension its important to register on intstall and unregister on uninstall your addin. It could be done with any Installation mastering technology/tool. There are many - MSI, Wix, InstallShield, Wise installer, NSIS, ...

For Addin-Express there is tutorial for Visua Studio MSI and Wix, find it here:

http://www.add-in-express.com/docs/internet-explorer-addons-deployment.php

When you will be using this tutorial, I suggest to select Wix, because MSI mastering (Visual Studio MSI) in Visual Studio is deprecated since VS 2012.